# business view by default

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a map to my website, but I would like to have it show the `business view` by **default** rather than going from `satellite to street view and then to business view`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If `business view` is what is now called [indoor map](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/), once you reach the view you should like to show on a map, you could simply retrieve the link to the view or to the iframe embed code, as explained in https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?hl=en

indoor map example: https://goo.gl/maps/SAhHg5hhLrGdLjaJ9

However, embedding the map via iframe source code gives you limited chances of customization.

If you need a higher level of customization  you can use the [street view service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) of [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview)  (you will need an [API KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) )

example: http://jsfiddle.net/eg561mx8/

```
var lat2 = 48.87708978509529, lng2 = 2.3392088036591754;


var map;
var panorama;
var panoramaService;
var streetView;

function initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  streetView = map.getStreetView();
  panoramaService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  panoramaService.getPanoramaByLocation(
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2),
    100,
    function(streetViewPanoramaData, streetViewStatus) {
      if (streetViewStatus != "OK") {
        alert("no street view at this location I'm afraid");
      } else {
        streetView.setPosition(
          streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng);
        streetView.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  );



}
```